# Not able to use nth-child to space out li's in a tags

Tags: html, css, margin, spacing, css-selectors

**http://codepen.io/leongaban/pen/uJDIw**

---

Hi, so in the **codepen above**, I'm trying to space out the buttons in the top row like the buttons in the bottom row.

Before adding the a tags I was able to get my spacing to work using:

```
.profile-crop-buttons ul li:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

However now that I've added the a tag, I haven't found the right syntax to target the 2nd child and give it left and right margins.

All tips appreciated! Thanks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you can't have an `<a>` as a direct child of a `<ul>` or `<ol>` only a `<li>` is valid so you want to switch the order of those around.

`.profile-crop-buttons ul li:nth-child(2)` is not working because as mentioned above the `<li>` is not a child of the `<ul>` the `<a>` is (the nth-child pseudo-class only selects a child of a given element not later descendants), but once you swap the order around the selector will work as expected.

[**Example**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ewFyn)

Comment: Ah thanks! That works, also I just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/910850/jquery-assign-onclick-for-li-from-a-link which was really what I was trying to do, I didn't actually need the a tag after all :) Gotta wait another 5 before I can check your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You still have to give margin to the `li` element not the `a` tag.

In your CSS, change

```
.profile-crop-buttons ul li a:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

to

```
.profile-crop-buttons ul li:nth-child(2) {
    margin: 0 20px 0 20px;
}
```

That should work. :)