# jQuery: expand one list item at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

As you can see [here](http://na.mobame.com/player/raykl/match/1418701693) I'm trying to only expand the summoner's extra match information to the one below it. But the arrow is expanding them all.

I was trying to make use of the code I've gotten from [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910850/jquery-assign-onclick-for-li-from-a-link), but I'm not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
$('div.the-player li.listed-player .more').click(function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if(!$target.is("div.the-player li.player-details")) {
        $('div.the-player li.player-details').animate({ height: "187px" });
    }
});
```

**Supporting Oleg's answer**

I've added the ability to check if the height is currently at 0 before making the animation happen for expanding. If it's already expanded, then you can make a closure back to 0px. Additionally, I've removed `margin-bottom` from the CSS and added it to the animation so that it will happen at the same time (making it a smoother animation) and not look like 20px have been chunked when it's closing. Because the item goes back to 0 height, it will also take the margin with it, thus a chunky disappearing act, so let's be simultaneous about it.

```
$('div.the-player li.listed-player .more').click(function(e) {
    var $target = $(this).closest('div.the-player').find('li.player-details');
    if($target.height() == 0) {
        $target.animate({ height: "187px", marginBottom: "20px"});
    } else {
        $target.animate({ height: "0px", marginBottom: "0px" });
    }
});
```

Comment: `$('div.the-player li.player-details').animate({ height: "187px" });` would animate all elements with that class. You probably want to reference `$target`

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. I was looking at that, but I've never actually used that before, so I'm actually sure how to target a descendent. I wish I could do as much with jQuery as I do with PHP.

Comment: Oleg's answer below would work, or you can also use `parent`  `$target.parent().parent().find('.player-details')` to traverse up to the common parent and animate that. `closest` is nice, since it doesn't bind your script and mark up too much (assuming you change things around)

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. Yea! I've also added a slight work to also close the extra box as well.

Comment: @mrxxiv Nice! I saw your comment below about the closure not being smooth, but on my end (Chrome), things are nice and smooth!

Comment: @JackPattishallJr. You know how when an object is 0px, the margin-bottom won't render? That's the fix I'll have to create. I'm on Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the area to expand relative to the button that was clicked:

```
$('div.the-player li.listed-player .more').click(function(e) {
    var $target = $(this).closest('div.the-player').find('li.player-details');
    $target.animate({ height: "187px" });
});
```

Explanation:

- $(this) is the element that was clicked
- .closest('div.the-player') looks in the ancestors (of $(this)) and returns the closest ancestor (parent element) that matches 'div.the-player'
- .find('li.player-details') looks in the descendents (of the 'div.the-player' element) and returns all of the child elements that match 'li.player-details'

In other words, we first find the first common container that we know both the button and the area to expand belong to. Then, we look inside that container to find the area to expand.

Comment: This is it! I really appreciate the correction. I've also added the if statement to check `if($target.height() == 0)` so that I can also animate the closure. But I think the closure isn't smooth.

Comment: Ahh, it's the margin, because when the height is gone, the margin won't show either.